# SafariExtensionBar: keep toolbar extension displayed in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I created a safari toolbar extension as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingExtensionToolbars/AddingExtensionToolbars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH5-SW2

Everything works fine, however, when safari is opened in fullscreen the toolbar is hidden by default and shows only when the mouse is moved to the top of safari.

Is there a way to always show the bar?

Comment: I think you can try posting your question http://apple.stackexchange.com/ here ...

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254456/safariextensionbar-keep-toolbar-extension-displayed-in-fullscreen